# How do 3 non-collinear points provide stability for an object?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I know that 3 non-collinear points form a unique plane. However, I have a hard understanding why a unique plane would provide stability for an object (eg. a stool with 3 legs). Could someone explain this?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: You might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2674000/318422) interesting. In that answer, *base* is the unique plane. If you have four legs, one of which is shorter or longer than others, the base is split into two separate planes, which each plane being stable (as modeled as described in that answer) separately, and the object easily tilted from one to the other. Tipping occurs when the center of mass projected to the supporting plane switches from one plane to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about why a table is unstable it is because one of the legs is too short. When someone leans on the table it pivots about the line defined by the ends of two of the legs and settles into a new plane. This cannot happen if there are only three legs because there is only one plane into which the table can settle.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what
the lengths of the legs,
there is a unique plane
that they lie in.
This means that,
when placed on the ground,
the table will be stable.

Also, if the lengths of the legs
are about the same,
then the top of the table
will be close to
horizontal.